# Build libev on android ndk

Tags: android-ndk, static-libraries, libev

I'm coding a program that really need libev (not libevent) on Android. I google many time to find how to build libev but unsuccess. 
Could any one tell me, how to build libev on android. Thank so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you have any success? I'm stuck with the same problem, trying to use it on a native app for Android (working on Ubuntu). This article gave me some light:

http://pod.tst.eu/http://cvs.schmorp.de/libev/ev.pod#EMBEDDING

It might be useful for you. I tried the standalone case. In any case, I can't  still make it work